# Bouncy Castle With Network Stream

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to create a streaming cyrpto wrapper.  I have a network connection that streams data down encrypted and I would like to decode it on the fly.  Here is a link to the same functionality using the native crypto classes, but I need to do it with Bouncy Castle.

https://github.com/pdelvo/Pdelvo.Minecraft/blob/master/Pdelvo.Minecraft.Network/AesStream.cs

I tried using BufferedStreamCipher but could not figure out how to get it to work and could not find any examples.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears to be AES in CFB8 mode, and you need a Stream.

You can get the enc/dec cipher objects with

> CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CFB8/NoPadding");

You have to call Init on each, with

> new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(keyBytes), ivBytes)

Then you can wrap a (bidirectional) Stream with them:

> new CipherStream(innerStream, readCipher, writeCipher)

That will probably get you started, but I am not %100 sure it will stream in quite the way you need. Give it a go though. Get back to me or post to the BC C# mailing list if there's something we can do to improve it.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I do need a bidirection stream (read/write).   I think this will work and will give it a try.  Thank you!

Comment: I have another somewhat related question.  From my understanding, using CFB8, I have to decrypt each chunk in order to get valid data.  What I am trying to do is:  Decrypt chunk 1, do not decrypt chunk 2, decrypt chunk 3.  WHat I see is that chunk 3 is invalid since I skipped one.  Is my understanding correct?  Is there any way to get chunk 3 to decrypt properly?  I tried reset and recreating the cipher, but neither works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: As I understand it, for CFB decryption, it will fix itself after one block (in this case of CFB8, just one byte). So, you can skip, but you need to allow for the first block you read next to be discarded. So, for CFB8 I would expect you can skip to 1 byte before the real destination, read (and discard) a byte, then continue. If the block size is >1, then you need to deal with block alignment too. Please see "Applied Cryptography" (Schneier), 9.6: Error Propagation.

Comment: Well, I went and read that section from Applied Cryptography myself, and realised my guesses about the amount of extra discard you need for CFB8 were wrong in my previous comment. It's something more like 8-9 bytes, certainly you should research it a bit for yourself and experiment!